# Using Kiwi's password reset through the "forgot password" link displays 500 Internal Server Error. Is this an issue with settings at common.py?

Tags: django, kiwi-tcms

Recently I had to change another user's password due to a probable typo. Using the login page's "forgot password" displayed a 500 error. Looking through Kiwi's dashboard, documentation, and github discussions, it was said that users can only change their own passwords. While I have worked around the issue (unable to change password) by using

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py changepassword userNameHere
```

, I want to know if the cause for the initial 500 error is due to a settings issue in Kiwi's common.py file or it is something else entirely.

Tried

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/610
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#quick-example

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_FROM = 'mail'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'kiwi@example.com'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Kiwi-TCMS] '
```

Expected to be able to use password reset aimed towards the user's set email address.

Actual is the 500 error.

New to this btw.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

These logs?:

```
IP - - [09/Aug/2019:02:52:07 +0000] "GET /accounts/passwordreset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1944 "https://kiwitcms.domain.com/accounts/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"
IP  - - [09/Aug/2019:02:52:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
IP  - - [09/Aug/2019:02:52:08 +0000] "POST /accounts/passwordreset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 8241 "https://kiwitcms.domain.com/accounts/passwordreset/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"
```

Additionally, traceback doesnt seem to be working even after product.py's DEBUG is True. Is this the bug you are referring to?

The question from another angle: Should the password reset function work after installing Kiwi or must I configure it, if so, what is required for config.

EDIT 2:
Are these logs relevant? 
Used  `docker logs container | grep -i error`

```
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.408480 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 8] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.22.0.3:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.22.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.429943 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.430535 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 8] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.22.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.430689 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 8] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.22.0.3:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.433497 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_wsgi/4.6.7 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 13 06:59:25.433519 2019] [core:notice] [pid 8] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Ive tested it locally without changing the common and product files so it couldn't be misconfigured. Between migrating the DB schema and creating the superuser, is there an additional step required to configure the email backend?

EDIT 3:
Finally got the traceback to show following the example from oritgaon at

```
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/631
```

Traceback:

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  220.         return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in form_valid
  233.         form.save(**opts)

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/kiwi_auth/forms.py" in save
  95.             extra_email_context,

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
  295.                 email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in send_mail
  250.         email_message.send()

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  291.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  103.             new_conn_created = self.open()

File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  63.             self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py" in **init**
  251.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py" in connect
  336.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  307.                                         self.source_address)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py" in create_connection
  724.         raise err

File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py" in create_connection
  713.             sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: OSError at /accounts/passwordreset/
Exception Value: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Comment: 500 is a bug but without a traceback/logs there's nothing else to do here.

Comment: The logs shown don't help. We need the error logs, where the traceback is. What you show here are access logs which show only which page is visible. If you are setting `DEBUG = True` you have to restart the application and the traceback will be shown in the web browser instead.

Comment: I have rebooted the ec2 instance, docker containers, and remade them with docker-compose, yet the traceback is still not shown. Is there anything else I need to change besides the Debug values of common and product? & Should the password reset function work after installing Kiwi or must I configure it?

Comment: Followed every step from https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html and noticed that registering a superuser through the browser interface does not send a confirmation email, therefore, will not be able to activate the user. The creation of a superuser using the command line works but doesnt send the confirmation email as well. Based on this, am I correct to assume the configuration for Kiwi's email is the issue here?

Comment: Probably your email backend isn't configured/misconfigured but without a traceback we can't tell. I have no idea why you are not seeing this in the docker error logs (apache error logs essentially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue, first go through https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html

**TO DISPLAY TRACEBACK:**

- Create local_settings.py under Kiwi dir and type:

  DEBUG = True
- Save
- In docker-compose.yml: Add line below as per https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/631 to volumes

  ./local_settings.py:/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/settings/local_settings.py
- Run "docker-compose down" then "docker-compose up -d".

**TO ENABLE EMAIL FOR REGISTRATION AND PASSWORD RESET:**

- The config I used REQUIRED a gmail account with 2FA enabled as well as App Password set.
- In local_settings.py: Add code below.

  EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

  EMAIL_PORT = '587'

  EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yourGmailAccountHere'

  EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourAppPasswordHere'

  EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
- Save and recompose.

In summary: My installation of Kiwi required configuration of email settings for the password reset and registration email to work.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I've opened a feature request to add a troubleshooting command. You can vote for it here: https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1070

Comment: Between migrating the DB schema and creating the superuser, is there an additional step required to configure the email backend?